# How to GET a URL with User-Agent and timeout through some Proxy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, proxy, get

How do I get a URL if I need to get it through some **proxy**, it has to have a **timeout** of max n. seconds, and a **User-Agent**?

```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'net/http'
   require 'rexml/document'

   def get_with_max_wait(param, proxy, timeout)
     url = "http://example.com/?p=#{param}"
     uri = URI.parse(url)
     proxy_uri = URI.parse(proxy)
     http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 80, proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port)
     http.open_timeout = timeout
     http.read_timeout = timeout
     response = http.get(url)
     doc = Nokogiri.parse(response.body)
     doc.css(".css .goes .here")[0].content.strip
   end
```

The code above gets a URL through a proxy with timeout, but it's missing the **User-Agent**. How do I get it **with** User-Agent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075954/user-agent-in-http-requests-ruby

Comment: @BlazeBoy - no, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use open-uri and set the user agent as parameter in open function .

Below is an example where I am setting user Agent in a variable and using that as parameter in open function .

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'

    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.854.0 Safari/535.2"

    url = "http://www.somedomain.com/somepage/"

    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, 'proxy' => 'http://(ip_address):(port)', 'User-Agent' => user_agent, 'read_timeout' => 10 ), nil, "UTF-8")
```

There is an option to set readtime out in openURI

You can review the documentation of Open URI in the below link

[Open URI documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html)

Comment: Ok, but where do you have there the proxy and timeout?

Comment: @valk sorry I updated now please check now I updated the post to use time out

Comment: @valk please check the code too , I have updated the code , with the new parameter

Comment: I guess you're using ruby 2.0. I'll just accept this. Although I was looking the answer for 1.9.3, I had to mention that... Thanks.