# Ruby equivalent for setting HTTP GET headers

Tags: ruby, http-headers

In C# it was fairly simple and didn't take more than a couple minutes to google:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.example.com?q=someValue");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth realm=\"example.com\" oauth_consumer_key=\"BCqrstoO\" ... so on and so forth");
string resultString = "";
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), true))
{
    resultString = read.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Trying to do it in Ruby hasn't quite been as straight forward (or is just something stupid that I'm missing).
I have been looking and the closest things I've come to finding my answer are [How to make an HTTP GET with modified headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587559/how-to-make-an-http-get-with-modified-headers) and [Send Custom Headers in Ruby](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/send-custom-headers-ruby).

So my problem, I suppose, boils down to

1. How do I set the headers as just a just a straight forward string?
2. Why do these two examples show headers formatted the way they are?
3. Is what I'm asking for even good convention and if not, how do I format what I'm trying to do in the convention these Ruby methods are asking for?

So far I tried the two examples and here's my most recent non-working attempt:

```
headers = "Authorization: OAuth realm=\"example.com\" oauth_consumer_key=\"BCqrstoO\" ... so on and so forth" 
uri = URI("www.example.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.get(uri.path, headers) do |chunk|
  puts chunk
end
```

Comment: May help if you remove the C# tag and just ask about adding headers to an HTTP request in Ruby. In an HTTP request, headers are just key/value pairs separated by a colon. So in your example the key is 'Authorization' and the value mapped to that key is all the stuff to the right.

Comment: What have you tried? Or, at least, what is the code you're currently using to make the request?

Comment: @Despertar So essentially all I need need to set it in this fashion: 'Authorization' => 'OAuth realm=\"example.com\" oauth_consumer_key=\"BCqrstoO\" ... so on and so forth' ?

Comment: @PaulBakerSaltShaker Yep, that looks good. Diego's example below should be spot on what you are looking to do. You can add whatever key/value pairs you need to, such as the oauth one you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Use [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html). Example:

```
require 'open-uri'

open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/",
    "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}",
    "From" => "foo@bar.invalid",
    "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
    # ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you check this at this point on time, the Net:HTTPRequest object allows you to add headers easily.

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
    request['my-header'] = '1'
    http.request request do |response|
        puts response
    end
end
```

Comment: more info on this, and examples, at ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html